# CSS help: Autoplay 6 images in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autoplay

I know this has been asked many times before, and I tried to look at the answers and follow them. But I just can't seem to figure out how to apply those answers with my specific code and now i'm stuck. If anyone could look over it and help me it would be very appreciated.

Simply, I just want to make an autoplay feature that plays those 6 images and  can also play and pause. Ideally with one button. That's all.
[JSfiddle link. Though it has no pictures. Maybe it helps?][1]

```js
window.onload = function() {

  function show1() {
    document.getElementById("showingImage").src = "images/.jpg";
  }

  function show2() {
    document.getElementById("showingImage").src = "images/2.jpg";
  }

  function show3() {
    document.getElementById("showingImage").src = "images/3.jpg";
  }

  function show4() {
    document.getElementById("showingImage").src = "images/4.jpg";
  }

  function show5() {
    document.getElementById("showingImage").src = "images/5.jpg";
  }

  function show6() {
    document.getElementById("showingImage").src = "images/6.jpg";
  }

  var one = document.getElementById("one");
  one.onmouseover = show1;

  var two = document.getElementById("two");
  two.onmouseover = show2;

  var three = document.getElementById("three");
  three.onmouseover = show3;

  var four = document.getElementById("four");
  four.onmouseover = show4;

  var five = document.getElementById("five");
  five.onmouseover = show5;

  var six = document.getElementById("six");
  six.onmouseover = show6;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}
#showingImage {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
}
#thumbnail {
  max-height: 50px;
  margin: 10 auto 10 10;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
HTML:

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div>
      <img id="showingImage" src="images/1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="thumbnail">
      <span id="one"><img id="thumbnail" src="images/1.jpg"></span>
      <span id="two"><img id="thumbnail" src="images/2.jpg"></span>
      <span id="three"><img id="thumbnail" src="images/3.jpg"></span>
      <span id="four"><img id="thumbnail" src="images/4.jpg"></span>
      <span id="five"><img id="thumbnail" src="images/5.jpg"></span>
      <span id="six"><img id="thumbnail" src="images/6.jpg"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Bonus points if you could explain how apply the Jquery fadeIn to the mouseover part and the autoplay.

Comment: Your JSFiddle link needs more link.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I refactored the `show` and `mouseover` functions into a single function apiece; the `show()` function uses jQuery's `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` effects. The button starts and stops the slideshow. I also changed your CSS a bit so that the images have unique `ids` and `thumbnail` is a class.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var playing;
  var currentImage = 1;

  // show an image with 200ms fade in/out effects
  function show(img) {
    $("#showingImage").fadeOut(200, function() {
      $("#showingImage").attr("src", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76726218/images/" + img + ".jpg").fadeIn(200);
    });
  }

  // initialze the mouseover
  $("img.thumbnail").mouseover(function() {
    console.log($(this));
    show($(this).attr("id"));
  });

  // start autoplay with 1s per image
  function play() {
    if (!playing) {
      playing = setInterval(function() {
        show(currentImage + 1);
        currentImage++;
        currentImage %= 6;
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  // pause autoplay
  function pause() {
    clearInterval(playing);
    playing = false;
  }

  // set up the button to toggle between play & pause
  $("#playPauseButton").click(function(e) {
    if (playing) {
      pause();
      $("#playPauseButton").html("Play");
    } else {
      play();
      $("#playPauseButton").html("Pause");
    }
  });

  // start autoplay
  play();

}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
#showingImage {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
}
.thumbnail {
  max-height: 50px;
  margin: 10 auto 10 10;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <img id="showingImage" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76726218/images/1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <span><img id="1" class="thumbnail" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76726218/images/1.jpg"></span>
    <span><img id="2" class="thumbnail" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76726218/images/2.jpg"></span>
    <span><img id="3" class="thumbnail" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76726218/images/3.jpg"></span>
    <span><img id="4" class="thumbnail" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76726218/images/4.jpg"></span>
    <span><img id="5" class="thumbnail" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76726218/images/5.jpg"></span>
    <span><img id="6" class="thumbnail" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76726218/images/6.jpg"></span>
  </div>
  <button id="playPauseButton">Pause</button>
</div>
```